# checking if a list is a key in a dictionary and returning corresponding value

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    table = {}
    for lines in f:
        co1,co2,co3,pro1,pro2,pro3 = (
            item.strip() for item in lines.split(',',5))
        codon=str(co1 + co2 + co3)
        table[codon] = pro2

print(table)
```

I need to split the `dan_seq` whatever they say it is into chunks of 3 and then match it to the dictionary I created
i.e. if the chunk is a key in my dictionary, return the value of it

```
dna_seq = list('AAAGTTAAATAATAAATAGGTGAA')
```

the picture is the text file:

[image: 1]

Comment: It's a CSV file *(highly likely)*, so you can use built-in [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) to not reimplement columns reading logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing to chunk up the `dna_seq`, and then `table.get` to get the matching values:

```
>>> dna_seq = 'AAAGTTAAATAATAAATAGGTGAA'
>>> [dna_seq[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(dna_seq), 3)]
['AAA', 'GTT', 'AAA', 'TAA', 'TAA', 'ATA', 'GGT', 'GAA']
>>> for chunk in [dna_seq[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(dna_seq), 3)]:
...     print(table.get(chunk))
```

Comment: I keep getting an error to say it's an unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: That's because you made `dna_seq` a list.  If you can just remove the `list()` around it do that; otherwise you can turn it back into a string by doing `''.join(dna_seq)`.

Comment: would you be able to look at my new post as when I put the code in a separate function it won't come up as defined

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the string into chunks of size 3, which you can accomplish by: `dna_seq[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(dna_seq), 3)` and your final code would look somewhat like:

```py
for i in range(0, len(dna_seq), 3):
    current_seq = dna_seq[i:i+3]
    
    # check if this value exists, then print it
    if current_seq in table:
        print(table[current_seq])
```

Comment: please check my new post on why this won't work when i try create it as a function